# Error :StreamJsonRpc.ConnectionLostException: The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019

My unit tests disappear from TestExplorer of visual Studio 2019 16.3.5

The output from test engine is:

```
[16/10/2019 6:45:48.705  Error] StreamJsonRpc.ConnectionLostException: The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__92`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.ClientSession.<InitializeConnectionAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Extensibility.TaskExtensions.<WithExceptionLogger>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
[16/10/2019 6:45:48.728  Error] StreamJsonRpc.ConnectionLostException: The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete. ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at StreamJsonRpc.MessageHandlerBase.<WriteAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<TransmitAsync>d__113.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.ThrowIfCompletedUnsuccessfully()
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__92`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__92`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.ClientSession.<OpenAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
[16/10/2019 6:45:48.730  Error] StreamJsonRpc.ConnectionLostException: The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete. ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at StreamJsonRpc.MessageHandlerBase.<WriteAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<TransmitAsync>d__113.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.ThrowIfCompletedUnsuccessfully()
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__92`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__92`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.ClientSession.<OpenAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.OpenOperation.<ExecuteInternal>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Operation.<<Execute>b__37_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Extensibility.ILoggerExtensions.<CallWithCatchAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
[16/10/2019 6:45:54.706  Error] StreamJsonRpc.ConnectionLostException: The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete. ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at StreamJsonRpc.MessageHandlerBase.<WriteAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<TransmitAsync>d__113.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.ThrowIfCompletedUnsuccessfully()
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__92`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__92`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.ClientSession.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.<<GetAllTestSources>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.ClientSession.<CallOnBackgroundThreadWithProgressAsync>d__59`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.TestContainer.TestContainerProvider.<SyncContainersAsync>d__45.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.TestContainer.TestContainerProvider.<RefreshContainersAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.OperationBroker.<TriggerAutoDiscoveryAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.OperationBroker.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<<OnSolutionOpened>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Extensibility.ILoggerExtensions.<CallWithCatchAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
[16/10/2019 6:47:49.853  Error] StreamJsonRpc.ConnectionLostException: The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete. ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at StreamJsonRpc.MessageHandlerBase.<WriteAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<TransmitAsync>d__113.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.ThrowIfCompletedUnsuccessfully()
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__92`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__92`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.ClientSession.<>c__DisplayClass55_0.<<RemoveTestSourcesAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.ClientSession.<CallOnBackgroundThreadWithProgressAsync>d__60.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.DiscoveryOperation.<DetectChangedContainers>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.DiscoveryOperation.<StartDiscoverTestsAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Operation.<<Execute>b__37_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Extensibility.ILoggerExtensions.<CallWithCatchAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
[16/10/2019 6:48:49.563  Error] StreamJsonRpc.ConnectionLostException: The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete. ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at StreamJsonRpc.MessageHandlerBase.<WriteAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<TransmitAsync>d__113.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.ThrowIfCompletedUnsuccessfully()
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__92`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__92`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.ClientSession.<CallOnBackgroundThreadWithProgressAsync>d__60.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.ClientSession.<InitializeExtensionsAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Core.Controller.TestPlatformExtensionManager.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<<InitializeExtensions>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Core.Controller.TestPlatformExtensionManager.InitializeExtensions(Boolean skipNonManagedTestExtensions)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.OnBeforeExecuteRequest()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Request.Start()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Operation.<ExecuteRequestAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.DiscoveryOperation.<StartDiscoverTestsAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Operation.<<Execute>b__37_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Extensibility.ILoggerExtensions.<CallWithCatchAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
```

All projects in the solution are build under `framework 4.8`
All have `Any Cpu` as `Platform Target`. 
Not as `32-bit prefer` option active.
I have x64 arquitecture selected for tests.
There is no testFile settings in use.

I try rebuild, clean rebuild, resinstall VS, nothing work. I can't find out what this error is.

Comment: Many posts point as solution to reinstall .net framework 4.8. It didn't work for me. I went back to version 16.2. The framework can be downloaded from here. learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history . Still waiting for a solution to move forward.

Comment: Is being investigated https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/594971/vs-2019-crashes-on-load-the-json-rpc-connection-wi.html

Comment: I have the same problem. I moved from 2017 to 2019 and now suddenly I can't use TestMethods and the test explorer is empty. I've been looking for a solution for a few days now.

Comment: The problem disappear for me. My version is still 16.2 and i can't figure out what changed. I suspect that was some port conflict that prevented the service to start. What ever the problem was, before it disappears, it survive downgrade and reboot.

Comment: I just went back to VS 2017 quickly after upgrading to VS 2019. Seems like VS 2019 has a lot of weird and quirky issues.

Comment: Just upgraded from VS 2022 v17.8.3 to 17.8.4, and this error has resurfaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft recognized the problem and roll out a fix in version VS 2019 16.5.2.

It is available now as [VS 2019 16.5.2 Preview 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview#16.5.0-pre.2.0)

Comment: In my case just updating to 16.4.5 (current release version) was enough.

Comment: This error has been around and can occur for many reasons. Check other posts for possible solutions. Note that the once it happens, you will have to restart VS. I causes some process to crash. Look for visual studio logs for more information about the crash.

Comment: 16.6.0 and restarting visual studio and restarting my machine is not working

Comment: 16.8.3, up to date, still pops up every time i restart VS.

Comment: 16.10.3 on VS 2019 still happening.

Comment: There are many reasons why tests won't show. Check if the test engine is running and check the test engine log for clues.

Comment: I've VS 2022 and the same error.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue workaround try this command in the in run window "devenv /ResetSettings", It worked for me.

Comment: Then had to restart VS.NET

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue in Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.5.4, but restarting VS fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by running Visual Studio as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when running Visual Studio 2019
You can type this statement in the run window
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /NoSplash /ResetSettings General /Command Exit" 
Note, first enter the address of the executable file of the desired version 
It is going to be alright

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This error appeared for me whenever I tried to start Visual Studio 2022, after upgrading to version 17.8.4; I would get this error in a pop-up, and then it would disappear.  Turns out it was related to a bad binding for System.Numerics.Vector inside of something called the IdentityService.  Adding a binding redirect to Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.exe.config to look for version 4.1.4 instead of 4.1.3 of System.Numerics.Vector fixed it for me:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Numerics.Vectors" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.4.0" newVersion="4.1.4.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score -1):

Faced this issue in following version. Clean and Rebuild Solution worked for me.
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.6.3

Comment: unfortunately right now, only solution for the Visual Studio 2019 Community Preview v16.8.0 Preview 4.0 restarting the Visual Studio, clean & rebuild didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by closing and opening VS.

Everything worked (VS2019) and suddenly started failing with a similar (did not compare word to word) callstack.
Rebuilding did not help, neither did manually killing hung processes from test console.
After re-opening VS - everything back to normal

Answer (score -1):

Just had the same on VS2022.  Closed VS, deleted the bin folder of the project, re-opened it in VS, ran it and it all worked fine after that.