# How to resolve warnings about internal errors in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I recently upgraded VS 2022 to the latest version and now I start seeing these warnings:

[image]

I am using version 17.4.0:

[image]

The stack traces look something like:

```
StreamJsonRpc.ConnectionLostException : The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete. ---> System.OperationCanceledException : The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at async StreamJsonRpc.MessageHandlerBase.WriteAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.SendAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.InvokeCoreAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at async StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.InvokeCoreAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.InvokeCoreAsync[TResult](<Unknown Parameters>)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.BrokeredServiceConnection`1.TryInvokeAsync[TService](<Unknown Parameters>)
```

Any ideas on fixing this? Never happened before.

Comment: Does it happen each time you open Visual Studio? If so, I would try a repair on Visual Studio (the installer has an option to do so).

Comment: @TimothyG. It seems to happen when I begin a build process.

Comment: Ok - I'd still start with a repair of Visual Studio.  Someone also suggested [resetting settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67034666/6530134), so you could also try that.  I saw a few logged issues on the Visual Studio Feedback forum that seem similar to this, so something could be bugged about this version of Visual Studio.  I am using the Preview version (17.5.0 Preview 1) and have not seen this happen.

Comment: I'm having the same issue since I upgraded to 17.4.0. It often happens after 30 to 60 minutes of having Visual Studio running. It seems to happen also when Visual Studio just runs in the background. Once such an error ocours in CodeAnalysis (ConnectionLostException), there's an endless bunch of these every few seconds.

Comment: @BenjaminFreitag Still does it in 17.4.1. See my link in comment to answer here.

Comment: Same issue in 17.4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is tracked at [Feature 'x' is currently unavailable due to an internal error](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Feature-x-is-currently-unavailable-due/10189905) and affects Visual Studio 17.4.0 and 17.4.1.

Comment: Yep. They closed mine as a duplicate. Side point: VS now creates a JSON for some reason too.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this problem using Visual Studio settings by navigating to
`Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced` and disabling:

> Run code analysis in a separate process (requires restart)

(I also unchecked its sub-setting "Run code analysis on latest .NET (requires restart)", for good measure.)

I got the idea from this ReSharper discussion:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-493691/VS-Feature-unavailable-due-to-an-internal-error

(This Visual Studio setting may help regardless of whether one uses ReSharper.)

Answer (score 2):

17.4.2 seems to have fixed things. at least for me,  I was only noticing it in my .net core app.

Comment: Me too, for now. And it has stopped creating the JSON folder.

Answer (score 1):

Report these using the Report A Problem tool.  The tool captures logs from the current VS session which may be helpful to the development team.  If you can trigger/reproduce the issue reliably, using the recording functionality can also collect dumps and ETL traces to help the investigation.

Comment: I put it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Task-list--Symbol-finder--Asset-synchr/10199226 But I have not provided them with the requested logs.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically it looks like this is a problem with the Roslyn compiler used by Visual Studio. For more information about Roslyn [check here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Resources/1913/what-is-roslyn.aspx). Although not "compiling" the code, Roslyn provides information about the code, such as syntax for Intellisense.

Per [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/64266) there's a recent (as of November '22) issue with Roslyn and it appears that these symptoms are a result of this cause. That suggests it will be resolved as part of an upcoming Visual Studio update.

For me the issue is reported with operations on the StreamJsonRpc object. I could only speculate why Roslyn uses StreamJsonRpc.

I have this with Visual Studio 2022 Professional v17.4.1 and others have reported it with v17.4.0. I was unable to resolve it by repairing Visual Studio or resetting its settings.

It was important for my own work to note that *it was not* a problem with my code. That prevented me spending hours on debug and package updates.

** On 11/29/22 Microsoft released Visual Studio version 17.4.2. I downloaded and installed it and I haven't seen these yellow warnings *yet*. I don't see Roslyn called out in the Microsoft release notes but the Roslyn issue referenced at the above URL was "Closed" today 11/30/22.

** On 12/2/22 I see the messages again so this cause is *not* resolved by the release of 17.4.3, at least for me.